# How to mock constructow without interference in legacy code

Tags: java, constructor, mockito

How to mock constructor without interference in legacy code using only Mockito (not PowerMockito). I made a research and I found some solutions but all of them base on interference on legacy code (creating factory, fake Method etc). Thanks for any responses. Here snippet of code:

```
    NyxBasicService<CreateAccountModel> accountService = new NyxBasicService<CreateAccountModel>(
        CreateAccountModel.class, null, sessionService);
```

To this time I used PowerMockito sth like this:

```
whenNew(NyxCommunicator.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(nyxCommunicator);
```

The thing is that I have to remove PowerMockito from my project and use only Mockito. Another thing is that inside constructor there is realy handsome amount of logic.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please provide the code that you want to test, and state what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito does not support this functionality. You have to either change the legacy code to use factories OR use Powermock.